# Issue with App Store Overlay: “Get the full app” Banner

Tags: ios, swift, storekit, apple-appclips

I am trying to present the “Get the full app” banner in the App Clip, the code was working fine, but after updating to Xcode 12.1 doesn't happen anything!. Did Apple change anything?

```
@objc func displayOverlay() {
    guard let scene = view.window?.windowScene else { return }
    let config = SKOverlay.AppConfiguration(appIdentifier: "TREXAC", position: .bottom)
    let overlay = SKOverlay(configuration: config)
    overlay.present(in: scene)
    print("heey banner")
}
```

[image]

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i have an issue when i click on the SKOverlay view it should navigate me to the Appstore but nothing happen whether it's on simulator or real device , is their something should i kept in consideration when testing the SKOverlay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `AppClipConfiguration` instead of `AppConfiguration`

```
guard let scene = view.window?.windowScene else { return }
let config = SKOverlay.AppClipConfiguration(position: .bottom)
let overlay = SKOverlay(configuration: config)
overlay.delegate = self
overlay.present(in: scene)
```

Comment: `UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first` is wrong. The OP’s code is much better.